# fadeIn only if not shown and fadeOut complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Please Check Edit's as it shows the progress I've made so far**
I'm having issues with calling jquery's `fadeOut` complete function.  I want the content to `fadeOut` completely before calling the `fadeIn`. 
 And I also don't want the content to `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` if its respective content is already displayed.  For example, if option 1's content is being displayed, and you click on option 1 again, it should not fadeout and back in, it should remain the same.

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/6kpyhpbh/7/

```js
$('.option1').click(function(){
$('.box').children().fadeOut(1000,function(){

$('.one').fadeIn();
});
});
$('.option2').click(function(){
$('.box').children().fadeOut(1000,function(){
$('.two').fadeIn();
});

});
$('.option3').click(function(){
$('.box').children().fadeOut(1000,function(){
$('.three').fadeIn();
});

});
```

```css
.cheese{
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  background:blue;
}
.cheese div{
  color:white;background:red;
}
.box{
  height:300px;
  width:500px;
  

}
.box .content{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cheese">
<div class="option1">Option 1</div>
<div class="option2">Option 2</div>
<div class="option3">Option 3</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="content one">Content One</div>
  <div class="content two">Content Two</div>
  <div class="content three">Content Three</div>
  
</div>
```

**EDIT 1:** I believe I solved the issue of not fading out properly before it fades in.  I used promise() and done, wierd that I need to do that to get it to work... Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/6kpyhpbh/10/

**EDIT 2:** So, I got both requirements to work, BUT there's an issue...if you click on two options quickly in succession, both show content up, I want only want the latest one to show up. https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/6kpyhpbh/16/

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the box as a whole fade out?

Comment: Can you clarify?  It doesn't for me.  It's targeting the children elements in the "box" only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `.not(":hidden")` function for fadeout functionality so that not every child fades out and hence the display issue.

```
$('.box').children().not(":hidden").fadeOut(1000,function(){
// code
});
```

Also you need to show atleast one element at the beginning which I have done for index 0.

```
$('.box').children().eq(0).show();
```

Please refer the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/50bjsv8t/).

Comment: I did something similar as well, I think I actually did the opposite of what you did: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/6kpyhpbh/16/, but here's another issue, if you click on two options quickly in succession, they both show up, I want only want the latest one to show up.

Comment: I have considered *EDIT 2*  and updated my fiddle. Please refer the above link. Have used `stop()` before fade animations.

Comment: Very nice, I believe this is doing exactly what I want it to, I'm not really understanding the eq(0) part but I'll probably research it more tomorrow after I sleep.  Thanks!

Comment: Always welcome. Also you can refer this link for info on `eq` - https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.option1').click(function(){
$('.box').children().hide(function(){
$('.one').show();
});
});
$('.option2').click(function(){
$('.box').children().hide(function(){
$('.two').show();
});

});
$('.option3').click(function(){
$('.box').children().hide(function(){
$('.three').show();
});

});
```

```css
.cheese{
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  background:blue;
}
.cheese div{
  color:white;background:red;
}
.box{
  height:300px;
  width:500px;
  transition-duration:0s;

}
*{transition-duration:0s;}
.box .content{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cheese">
<div class="option1">Option 1</div>
<div class="option2">Option 2</div>
<div class="option3">Option 3</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="content one">Content One</div>
  <div class="content two">Content Two</div>
  <div class="content three">Content Three</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't do what I asked, sorry.  It still rolls in instead of waiting for it to fadeout completely and it also still fades in if its content is already shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use the visibility check before doing a fade in or out:

```
If ($(.yourElement).is(":visible") )     
{
      //Do your fade out
}
```

You can disable/enable elements during animation

```
$(.yourElement).prop ('disabled', true);
$(.yourElement).fadeIn (1000, function () { 
    $(this).prop ('disabled', false);
});
```

or use the promise to perform your animation after all animations for that element

```
element.promise ().done ( function () {
    //Do something on completion of all animations
});
```

if you want it to trigger even if the element has already finished animating:

```
element.promise ().always ( function () {
    //Do something on completion of all animations
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `data-dir` html5 new feature to access different `.content` classes

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6kpyhpbh/17/

```
$('.box').children('div').hide();

 $('.cheese div').on('click',function(){
   var direction = $(this).data('dir')

   if(direction === 'option1'){
    $('.box').children('.contentOne').fadeIn().siblings('div').fadeOut();
   }
   if(direction === 'option2'){
    $('.box').children('.contentTwo').fadeIn().siblings('div').fadeOut();
   }
   if(direction === 'option3'){
    $('.box').children('.contentThree').fadeIn().siblings('div').fadeOut();
   }
 });
```